# substitute string character with a character from another string in C language

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

when i run this program, it crashes.
I would like to copy one char from one string to another.
Can you help me?
ex: I would like to have "wello" as array[0] instead of "hello"

```
int main()
{
    int N=3;
    char *array[10];
    array[10]=malloc(N*sizeof(char));
    array[0]="hello";
    array[1]="wall";
    array[2]="dinner";
    array[0][0]=array[1][0];
    printf("array[0][0]: %c\n", array[0][0]);
    printf("array[0]= %s, array[1]= %s, array[2]= %s", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems here:

1. `array` has only 10 elements, and hence none with index `10`.
2. You didn't allocate the space for the strings you assign into the first 3 elements of `array`, so may not be allowed to modify them.
3. Why does `array` have 10 elements if you only use 3? Why are you allocating space for the 11th if you never use it?

Answer (score 0):

None of your character pointers in your array point to valid memory locations. You need to do a `malloc` for each pointer to store a string in it.
Also, `array[10]` is outside of the index you've declared for `array` (which is 0 to 9).